# Kingpad K70 will not show up in ADM

Tags: android, android-studio

I've acquired (note: it wasn't MY decision to purchase this!) a Kingpad K70 by TabletExpress and it simply isn't cooperating when it comes to getting Android Studio to recognize it as a debug device. I've been searching all over for things to try, and here are the steps I've taken and the results based on what I've read.

1. Developer options were already turned on. Odd, because it won't talk to AS by default.
2. By default in Device Monitor, it shows up as a Media Device with the MTP USB Device driver installed, so...
3. Storage options > menu > USB computer connection and change it from "Media Device (MTP)" to "Mass Storage" ... from what I've read, this is as it should be to use it as a debug device.
4. After step 3, the tablet now shows up as two distinct devices, no name just location letters, under Portable Devices.
5. Tried to update device drivers using the autodetect option and I get the result that the "WPD Filesystem Volume Driver" is up-to-date.
6. Tried again using the browse/manual install option, default location of ~\Android\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver and get the same result as item 5.
7. Tried the browse/manual install again and this time used the "Let me pick..." option ... all I could see was the same driver with "Show compatible hardware" checked with the addition of MTP drivers if I unchecked that.

Yes, I checked the Android Developers page for OEM USB drivers and TabletExpress isn't there. When I contacted TabletExpress's technical support, they told me they'd never heard of Android Studio and that the best they could tell me was to contact the company that makes that program and let them know it was buggy.

Nothing I could figure out to do made that tablet show up as Android Phone > Android Composite ADB Interface.

Is there something I'm missing? Something else I should try? Or should I just hand it back to my business partner, ask him to return it and get something that works?

Comment: Do you have Android Studio's latest version installed ?

Comment: Yes, I do, and updates have been installed for 1.5.1

Comment: I should add that I've had other physical devices hooked up and working properly. This is the first one I've had any problems with.